# The use of *(char **)

Tags: c, pointers, char

The following code is from [The Practice of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161586X):

```
int scmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    char *v1, *v2;
    v1 = *(char **) p1;
    v2 = *(char **) p2;
    return strcmp(v1, v2);
}
```

I don't understand why using the expression `*(char **) p1`. Can we use `(char *)p1` instead?
What is the difference between them?

Thanks!

Comment: Context is important here to know what is being passed in as parameters. This question reveals what the text book intends as parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364153/pointer-cast-for-use-with-qsort

Comment: Sorry for duplicate, the link you provide gives more details than my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. The `(char **)` is a type cast, and the unary `*` which precedes the cast dereferences the pointer.  If you simply take `v1 = (char *) p1`, then `v1` will be set equal to `p1`, when what you want is for `v1` to be equal to the `char*` to which `p1` points.

Answer (score 3):

## An Example would help you understand

let there be strings `"yourString1"` and `"yourString2"`.

let `s1` be a pointer to "yourString1" and `s2` be a pointer to "yourString2"

```
s1->"yourString1"
s2->"yourString2"
```

calling `scmp(s1,s2);` causes `p1` to point to `s1` and  `p2` to point to `s2`

```
p1->s1->"yourString1"
p2->s2->"yourString2"
```

So, `p1`,`p2` are double pointers here..

Since `p1`,`p2` is a void pointer it would have to be converted to `char pointer`.

so,

`(char**)p1` would make p1 a char double pointer

`*(char**)p1` and `*(char**)p2` would now point to `s1` and `s2`.

This would allow strcmp to compare the strings on `s1` and `s2`

Answer (score 2):

The interface in this function is designed to be slightly more complex than it may first 
appear. One could design scmp to just take to pointers to strings (and this btw. is what *strcmp* does).

```
int scmp1(void * p1, void *p2) { return strcmp((char*)p1,(char*)p2);}
char *ptr = "bar";
char *ptr2 = "foo";

scmp1(ptr, ptr2); // this would make sense, however, 

scmp(&ptr, &ptr2); // this is how the interface is designed.
```

The compare function takes pointers to (pointers to strings) for no apparent reason.
Maybe the function will be in following chapters extended to *swap* the pointers inside the function -- then the caller would see ptr to point to "foo" and ptr2 to point to "bar". (This is not possible in scmp1 aka strcmp type function, where the pointers to be passed can be modified *locally* ie. in the scmp1 and strcmp function respectively, but no changes are propagated to the caller)

Comment: op is asking **why** `*(char **)` not **how**

Answer (score 2):

`(char**)p1` means *p1* is a pointer(the second * shows) that points to char*(char*).
So get the value `*(char**)p1`, and the result is *char*(we can say a string)*, could assgin to v1(type is *char**).
*void** could convert to any pointer*(char*,int*,double*)...*