# What is happening in this pointer to string compare function?

Tags: c, string, pointers, compare, void-pointers

```c
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **str_a = (const char **)a;
    const char **str_b = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*str_a, *str_b);
}
```

I know that this function is comparing the contents of an array of pointers to string. But I am not getting what is going on inside it - I am confused about the `**`, why it is used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer cast for use with qsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364153/pointer-cast-for-use-with-qsort)

Comment: @KenY-N Well it is a duplicate, but it got answers now. So now the question is which one that is the best question with the best answers out of these two. Not "which one is the oldest", that's irrelevant. We should close the post with lowest quality as a duplicate to the better one. I'm partial since I posted an answer, so I'll refrain from voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the typical callback function required by `bsearch`/`qsort`, which passes along two pointers to array items, to be compared by this function. It returns less than zero, zero or greater than zero if the first item is considered lesser, equal or greater than the second.

Now lets your array that needs searching/sorting is an array of pointers, such as a typical array of strings: `char* arr[] = { "hello", "world" };`

Then each item in this array is a `char*`. Meaning `bsearch`/`qsort` will pass a pointer to a character pointer, `const char**`, to the callback function.

Since `void*` specifically is a generic pointer, this is fine. We are allowed to convert from `const char**` to `const void*` and back. But we can't anything meaningful with a `const void*` so it needs to be cast to the expected type, then de-referenced so that `strcmp` gets two `const char*` parameters like it expects.

Comment: so these line                                                                                    
```   const char **str_a = (const char **)a;
    const char **str_b = (const char **)b; ```    are just to dereference and convert *void to **char?so that we can pass *char in strcmp ,right?                                                          thank you for you answer and explaining it .

Comment: @NitinBhartiya Yes indeed. `bsearch` internally takes a pointer to each array item (it doesn't know the item type), converts it to a "const correct" void pointer and then expects the person implementing `compare` to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

The function expects arguments to be pointers to pointers. Example use:

```
const char *a = "string";
const char *b = "string";
int result = compare(&a, &b);
```

Another example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    assert(argc >= 3);
    return compare(&(argv[1]), &(argv[2]));
}
```